# Different values depending on OS Version in Firebase remote config

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I want to give iOS 14.5 users random values in the firebase remote config.
There was no option for me to choose from in remote config > conditions.

[image]

So I tried to choose the option in Audiences, but the platform has two options: OS Version and Operating System with Version.

[image]

I tried 2 options each, but remote config only gives default.

Does anyone know how to set it according to the OS version in the remote config?

Comment: I checked a little more, and the user...
I think it's taking time to be part of Audiences.
Is there any way to speed up the time when users are added to Audiences?

Comment: I want to give different values depending on the system OS version in Google remote config, what should I do?

Comment: Jacob Lee, thank you for the correction.!

Answer (score 2):

I looked for the same functionality for android and ended up setting a custom user property for the OS version (`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in android). I would suggest to set it to a number rather than string so you will be able to target users starting at specific version (for example users with iOS 14+)

Once you do that you can use this you will be able to add this condition to targeting and distribution section of the A/B test or Conditional parameter in  remote configuration the same way I do it in the the attached image for experiments_toke_low custom property

[image]